# how to retrieve json objects using python?

Tags: python, json

i want to retrieve **objects of json file** using python i have a json file inside `c:/python/news.json` now i want to retrieve objects of json file.
my code is as follows

```
import json
with open("c:/python/news.json") as json_file:
     data=json.load(json_file)
print data
```

it always gives error as

```
invalid syntax
```

but its not working.
i want output as:

```
print data['news1']
```

then it should always give first news as my json is somthing like :

```
[
  {
     "news1": "BBC",
      "ur": "Lennon"

  },
  {


      "news2": "newstime",
      "ur": "Lennon"

  },

]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: This exact code works for me (except changing path due to linux). Python 2.7.

Comment: Provide your traceback

Comment: i don't know why it is not working on my windows system.

Comment: Just a note, that the last comma "," is not allowed in the strict JSON spec.  Remove it and try again.  I don't know json module implementation for Windows but it may use different JSON library if not pure Python.

Comment: @Kenji Noguchi thanx but still not working.. idon't know why its not working. can you plz help y its not working on windows ?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using python version 3.x, in which case you have to call print as a function:

```
print(data)
```

Otherwise it's a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Try running python --version and see what it says. There aren't any other syntax errors that I can see in your program.

Comment: yeah i am sure about it . its 2.7.5

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 3
   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Put it in a file and re-run. This traceback didn't come from the code you showed us. You entered it into the repl, but none of your indented blocks contain more than 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo--you write `josn_file`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the last **comma** in the file. It works for me after removing the last comma:

```
# news.json
[
    {
        "news1": "BBC",
        "ur": "Lennon"
    },
    {
        "news2": "newstime",
        "ur": "Lennon"
    }
]
```